# Xcode 6 playground — I can't create a OS X playground file

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, swift, xcode6

I've updated to Xcode 6, the latest one appeared on the AppStore. I am running OS X Yosemite Beta 3 and apparently, I can open up only the iOS playground and the OS X one is missing from the list.

I attached a screenshot. Hm, any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: I have the same problem on the latest version of Mavericks too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download Xcode 6.1 which has the swift for Mac OS X.

Also check this link: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/

```
Swift for OS X
Today is the GM date for Swift on iOS. We have one more GM date to go for Mac. Swift for OS X currently requires the SDK for OS X Yosemite, and when Yosemite ships later this fall, Swift will also be GM on the Mac. In the meantime, you can keep developing your Mac apps with Swift by downloading the beta of Xcode 6.1.
```

Comment: As of 2014-09-22 Xcode 6.1 is still in beta so you have to get it off the developer site for OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, if you start an empty project and chose OS X, you don't have swift as language. So only ObjectiveC as language for Cocoa-based apps. Maybe in Yosemite final this feature will be implemented. I think we should wait GM date for Swift & Yosemite to go for Mac.

Comment: I'm opening Xcode 6 and creating a playground file without selecting the language.